# how laravel autoload classes and use them without initiate it?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to deep dive laravel concept. In the very first step i got stuck. Loading different classes and use them.
In the laravel routing (where you can register web routes for your application), there is no any use keyword used for using class and initiate Route class in web.php

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

how Route::get run without using any class?

And when we go more deep using model class
    namespace hosam\Http\Controllers\Auth;

```
use hosam\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

and we use Auth in aur code like this.

```
 Auth::login($user);
```

from using use keyword does php load auth class in our code where we are using Use Auth?

Answer (score 0):

All the route files under `routes` folder are loaded automatically by laravel. `routes/web.php` and `laravel/api.php` are assigned to middleware web and api respectively.

All the classes and namespaces in laravel are loaded from the composer autoloader.

These files are mapped in the `RouteServiceProvider` class under `Provider` folder. So that class use Route facade. As the `web.php` and `api.php` is not called directly so there is no need to initiate the class in the particiular file

```
//RouteServiceProvider.php
Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

[Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing)

Comment: But how it use class without creating object of class like $object = new classname(); its directly using class like Auth::login();

Comment: login is a static method :: (scope resolution operator) is used to call the static method directly by using the class_name::static_function_name. That is the reason it does not need the instance of the class

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your Helper folder with HelperClass and run can be run from any where

1. make folder in `app > Helpers` folder.
2. make helper class `Helpers.php`
   where you can write all your function like

```
function write_yourfunction(){
 // your code
// return something
}
```

3. to load every where you can use service provider. Edit `app > Providers > AppServiceProvider.php`

```
 public function register()
    {
        foreach (glob(app_path() . '/Helpers/*.php') as $filename) {
            require_once($filename);
        }      

    }
```

4. Now you can call `write_yourfunction()` from everywhere